# How to call Selector instantly for SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

In `SWRevealViewController` for call `revealToggle:` (menu) need to:

```
someButton.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: Selector("revealToggle:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
```

But this work only if button pressed (`TouchUpInside`). How I can call it instantly? Just in `viewDidLoad` when `view` is shown

Comment: Why don't you just call revealToggle yourself in viewDidLoad...?

Comment: r u using stroyborad

Comment: Jeff, how I can do that?

Comment: self.revealViewController.revealToggle() etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.revealViewController.revealToggle()
```